# what's the syntax for Accessing smb/windows shares via alternative ports?

Tags: windows, file-sharing, server-message-block

when port forwarding on my router for port 139 to port 139 of my linux-smb based NAS is enabled running a simple \computername.*dynamicipserviceX*.com\sharename on windows works. However when set to any other port for example \computername.*mydynamicIpService*.com:999\sharename fails to function when the router is set to also forward that port to 139 internally, do I have the syntax wrong or is something else needed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't be done sorry.  Windows does not support TCP ports other than 445/139.  ([Here is one reference.](http://www.blisstonia.com/eolson/notes/smboverssh.php))

Answer (score 1):

You could try a Windows port of `rinetd` on the client machine, which would let you do something like this on the client machine:

```
#bindaddress  bindport connectaddress connectport
192.168.1.1   139      4.2.2.2        999
```

Assuming that worked, you could use your normal \servername.server.com\sharename from your client machine, and `rinetd` would change the connection port for that address.

This article: http://codewut.de/content/port-redirection-windows has more information and a patched binary. I haven't tried this myself, but it looks like it is worth attempting.

Comment: looks like this would work on the server for incoming requests, not the sender for outgoing, right?

Comment: You would set this up on the client, not the server. The server would still be set at 139 of course. You would keep the port mapping you had on the router.

Comment: [rinetd manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/rinetd.8.html)