# How to access shared folders on custom ports? (windows)

Tags: windows, samba, server-message-block

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what’s the syntax for Accessing smb/windows shares via alternative ports?](https://serverfault.com/questions/39180/whats-the-syntax-for-accessing-smb-windows-shares-via-alternative-ports)

Imagine I have this samba serving on a port different from the default (445). How do windows clients access those files?

Answer (score 4):

[They can't](https://serverfault.com/questions/39180/whats-the-syntax-for-accessing-smb-windows-shares-via-alternative-ports/39183#39183).  Windows clients can only see the default ports 139 and 445.